# Possible to get all businesses within an [x] mile radius of an address with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a solution to gather data on local businesses. In a nutshell, I need to input a street address/coordinates and get a listing of all other businesses that exist in a (for example) 3 mile radius. Will the Google Maps API work for this?

This will be a manual process so the requests will be very minimal: maybe 1 or 2 requests per month. This isn't a script that I am intending to run over and over again in any way to create a high volume requirement.

Comment: You need Google Places API for that. Google Maps API allows you to add the actual map to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Places API certainly is not designed to gather all businesses within the specified radius. The API returns only most prominent results and doesn't guarantee the complete list. This is not a traditional database search.

In addition there are restrictions in the Terms of Service that prohibit such kind of searches. Have a look at the paragraph 10.4 c (ii).

> **No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services**. You will not use Google’s Content or Services to create or augment your own mapping-related dataset (or that of a third party), including a mapping or navigation dataset, **business listings database**, mailing list, or telemarketing list.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4